# PHP 7.2.18 | Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this message running PHP 7.2.18

Edit: If it makes any difference, when I run PHP from the command line using php -v, it says I'm running 7.3.5

I run this command to install:
apt-get install php7.3mysqlnd

Here is the response generated:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.3-mysql' instead of 'php7.3-mysqlnd'
php7.3-mysql is already the newest version (7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone know what package I should be installing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to run:

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```